# How to write in input and get output in other input automatic my text

Tags: jquery

How to write in input and get output in other input automatic my text? I need it for Meta Title
Example:
input 1 i type manuel text "Audi A4"
input 2 i type manuel text "Car"
and it must be output me in input 3 text "Audi A4 - for sale (Car)"
how to make it with jQuery?

i tried with code, but it works only with 1 input

```
$("#title").keyup(function() {
  $("#meta_title").val($(this).val());
});
```

// this is input who will receive information from input #title and #time

```
<input type="text" name="meta_title" id="meta_title" class="form-control">
                 $("#title").keyup
                    (
                        function ()
                        {
                            $("#meta_title").val
                            (
                                $(this).val()
                            );
                        }
                    );
                 $("#xf_time").keyup
                    (
                        function ()
                        {
                            $("#meta_title").val
                            (
                                $(this).val()
                            );
                        }
                    );
```

if you write from the second, it replaces the text from the first
how to make it from both inputs added to the third

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Tell us what you have tried so far, show us some code. We are glad to help if you are stuck, but SO is not a code writing service.

Comment: $("#title").keyup
      (
       function ()
       {
        $("#meta_title").val
        (
         $(this).val()
        );
       }
      ); it works only with 1 input i tried, but how can i write from 2 inputs and get output in my meta title id

Comment: You are using ID's `#` so that will only select on element. If you want to do the same for multiple elements use classes `.`

Comment: that's a start, but still not a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Provide the HTML code of your three input fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the keyup event listener to both your target input fields and then concatenate the values. From what I could gather from your code, it should probably be something like this (I just assume your 2nd input field is named "category"):

```js
// bind the event listener to both fields
$('#title,#category').on('keyup', function() {
  // concatenate the values of both fields
  var metaTitle = $('#title').val() + ' - for sale (' + $('#category').val() + ')';
  // write it to the target field
  $('#meta_title').val(metaTitle);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="title" />
<input type="text" id="category" /> 
<input type="text" id="meta_title" />
```